# Prove that $\angle AIO = 90^{\circ}$ with $I$ being the incenter and $O$ circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

[image]

let $O_1$ be the center of the semicircle and $XY$ be its diameter. We must have $O_1A \perp XY$ and $O_1A > 2R = XY$ otherwise $\triangle ABC$ doesn't exist.

I also know that the semicircle is the $A$ excircle of $\triangle ABC$ and I also happen to know that $\angle AIO = 90^{\circ}\iff a = \frac{b+c}2$ where $a,b,c$ are the sides of $\triangle ABC$.

I found this problem to be quite challenging still, because it is hard to work with the constrain of a reflection over a line.

EDIT. **all the details**: we are given a circle $\omega = (O_1,R)$ and a point $A$ such that $O_1A > 2R$. $XY$ is the diameter of $\omega$ perpendicular to $O_1A$. Line $A_1A_2$ is the polar line of $A$ w.r.t. $\omega$. We reflect line $XY$ over line $A_1A_2$ and obtain the dotted line parallel to $XY$ which cuts $\omega$ at $T$. $B$ is the meeting of $AA_2$ with the tangent line from $T$ and $C$ is the meeting of that tangent line with $AA_1$. I want to prove that $\angle AIO = 90^{\circ}$ with $I$ and $O$ being respectively the incenter and circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$

[image]

EDIT: since all of you guys were so excited to prove my little $2a=b+c$ lemma, here is a little reward for you:

[image]

Comment: What your precise question is, please? (My English is not good enough)

Comment: @Piquito given that construction, show that $\angle AIO = 90^{\circ}$ with $I$ and $O$ being respectively the incenter and circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$

Comment: You might want to clarify the setup of the question, and not just rely on the diagram (or our ability to tell exactly what the various items mean). It's not clear to me what the problem setup is. Almost certainly, $\angle AIO \neq 90^\circ$ for an arbitrary triangle. I see some equal line segments drawn in the diagram, are those crucial?

Comment: What is the source of this question? Given that it was again posted [3 hours later](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693764/find-angle-x-in-triangle-below), also with few details, I suggest holding off on answering for now.

Comment: @CalvinLin source of the problem is a peruan book of geometry, but the question was posted on a brazillian forum which I and that other user partake. Sure, I will write down the details. Ofc as I posted before him, his question is the duplicate of mine and not the other way around.

Comment: @CalvinLin I hadn't seen that he had posted. We are part of the same forum and since no one could solve it I posted here, but deleted the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to give a clean synthetic approach.
It restates the given constellation having $\Delta ABC$ in foreground. (And not starting with the irrelevant diameter $XY$.) Then we translate all points and properties in terms of this triangle. For instance, $O_1$ is the excenter $I_A$. And the condition on $T$ gets translated as "mid point of $AI_A$ is on $BC$".
Known metric relations in a triangle, and formulas for the placement of
the incenter, and excenters together with their projections on the sides are used.
The answer became longer then it was initially intended, as i tried to introduce notations, restate clearly the bountied proposition by using them, collect facts, and make them conclude in a short computation. Let's start.

---

Observe first that $CO_1$ is the angle bisector of $\widehat{TCA_1}$, since
$CT$ and $CA_1$ are tangents from $C$ to a circle centered in $O_1$. (The triangles $\Delta CTO_1$ and $\Delta CA_1O_1$ are congruent, one right angle each, one radius side each, and a common side.) Similarly, $BO_1$ bisects
$\widehat{TBA_2}$, so $O_1$ is the $A$-excenter of $\Delta ABC$.
We would like to state the given constellation of points by starting from $\Delta ABC$ in an equivalent manner. The one needed translation is that of the condition that $T$ projects on $O_1A$ in the reflection of $O_1$ w.r.t. $A_1A_2$. So we...

> *Claim:*
> Let $A$ be a point, which is exterior to a circle $\omega$ centered in a point $O_1$ with radius $R$. Denote by $*$ the inversion $X\to X^*$ in $\omega$. We draw the tangents from $A$ to the circle, let $A_1$, $A_2$ be the points of tangency. In particular, $A_1A_2$ is the polar of the pole $A$ with respect to $\omega$.
> And $A^*$ is $A_1A_2\cap O_1A$.
> Let $S$ be the reflection of $O_1$ w.r.t. the polar $A_1A_2$.
>
> Let now $T$ be a point on the arc $\overset\frown{A_1A_2}$ (which is in the half-plane w.r.t. $A_1A_2$ containing $A$). Draw the tangent in $T$ to $\omega$. It intersects $AA_1$, and $AA_2$ in $C$, respectively $B$.
> Let $M$ be the intersection of lines
> $$
> M=BTC\cap O_1A\ .
> $$
> **Then** $T$ projects in $S$ on $O_1A$, if and only if (iff) $M$ is the mid point of $AO_1$.
> [image: excenter property in a constellation where X(1)X(3) is perpendicular on the A-angle bisector]

*Proof:*
Assume that $T$ projects in $S$. Then in the triangle $\Delta TMO_1$ with a right angle in $T$ we have a formula for $O_1S\cdot O_1M$ which leads to:
$$
O_1A^*\cdot O_1A
=O_1A_1^2=R^2=O_1T^2=O_1S\cdot O_1M=2O_1A^*\cdot O_1M\ .
$$
So $M$ is the mid point of $O_1A$. For the converse it is easy to adapt the same argument. (Denote by $S'$ the projection of $T$ on $O_1M$, and then similarly $O_1A^*\cdot O_1A
=O_1S'\cdot O_1M=O_1S'\cdot 2O_1M$, so $S'=S$.)

$\square$

---

Using the above, we can then restate the given problem:

> *Lemma:* Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle with incenter $I$ and $A$-excenter $I_A$.
> Its sides are $a,b,c$.
> Assume that the mid point $M$ of $AI_A$ lies on $BC$.
> **Then:** $2a=b+c$.

*Proof:* Denote by $S$ the area of $\Delta ABC$, by $s$ the half-perimeter $s=\frac 12(a+b+c)$, by $r$, $r_A$ the in-radius and the $A$-ex-radius, by $h_A$ the height from $A$. Then:
$$
\bbox[yellow]{\qquad r_A(s-a)=S=\frac 12ah_A\ .\qquad}
$$
(The formula $S=r_A(s-a)$ is similar to the handy known formula $S=rs$,
shown by area splitting $\Delta ABC$ in $\Delta IBC$, $\Delta ICA$, $\Delta IAB$. When replacing $I$ bay $I_A$, the first area is taken with the negative sign in the split.)

The assumption on $M$ shows that $A$ and $I_A$ have the same distance to $BC$:
$$
\bbox[yellow]{\qquad h_A=r_A\ .\qquad}
$$
This gives $s-a=\frac a2$, so $a+b+c=2s=3a$, so $b+c=2a$.

$\square$

*Observation:* By the same argument, the converse is also true.

---

It remains to show:

> *Proposition:* Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle. We use same notations as in the above *lemma*. Let us also introduce the circumcenter $O$. Assume that $$2a=b+c\ ,$$
> and that $O\ne I$. Then $AI\perp OI$.

*Proof:*
We denote by $R$ the circumradius, and use [Euler's relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry) $OI^2=R^2-2Rr$, and [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula).

We are successively using below *equivalent steps*
from one line to the next one
to translate $AI\perp OI$
into a relation between $a,b,c$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
AI&\perp OI\ ,\\
AI^2 &=AO^2-OI^2\ ,\\
AI^2&= R^2-(R^2-2Rr) \ ,\\
AI^2 &= 2Rr\ ,\\
\frac r{2R} &=\frac{r^2}{AI^2}\ .\\[3mm]
&\quad\text{Separated computation:}\\
&\quad\frac{r^2}{AI^2}=\sin ^2\frac A2=1-\cos ^2\frac A2
=\frac {1-\cos A}2
=\frac 12\left(1-\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\right)\\
&\quad\qquad=\frac 1{4bc}(a^2-(b-c)^2)=\frac 1{4bc}(a-b+c)(a+b-c)
\\
&\quad\qquad=\frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{bc}\ .\\[3mm]
\frac r{2R} &=\frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{bc}\ ,\\
r\; bc &=2R\; (s-b)(s-c)\ ,\\
2rs\;bc\; (s-a)&= 4R\;s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)\ ,\\
2S\;bc\; (s-a)&= 4R\;S^2\ ,\\
2bc\; (s-a)&= 4RS\ ,\\
2bc\; (s-a)&= abc\ ,\\
2(s-a)&= a\ ,\\
2s&=3a\ ,\\
a+b+c&=3a\ ,\\
b+c&=2a\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

$\square$

Answer (score 1):

HINT.- Let $A,B,C$ the vertex of the triangle $\triangle{ABC}$ and $a,b,c$ the sides; $O$ be the circumcenter and $I$ the incenter, $D$ and $E$ midppoints of sides $b$ and $c$ respectively.We can prove that $\angle AIO = 90^{\circ}$ an easy way, making carefully a striaghtforward calculation.

(1) Take $A$ as origin and as rectangular coordinate axes the bisector line in $A$ and its perpendicular in $A$, as shows the attached figure.

(2) the circumcenter $O$ is the point of intersection of the lines (bisectors of sides $AB$ and $AC$) $OD$ and $OE$ where $D$ and $E$ are midpoints of $AC$ and $AB$ respectively.

(4) the geometry of the figure allows us to establish that the segment $IO$ is parallel to the diameter $XY$, that is, that $IO$ is perpendicular to the bisector in $A$ of the triangle, if (and only if) the points $I$ and $O$ have the same second coordinate.

(3) The incenter is known to have as second coordinate $y_I=\dfrac{a\cdot0+b\cdot b_2+c\cdot c_2}{a+b+c}=\dfrac{b\cdot b_2+c\cdot c_2}{a+b+c}$ and the second coordinate of $O$, say $y_O$, is given by the intersection of the perpendicular lines  $OD$ and $OE$ to the lines $AC$ and $AB$ respectively. With the equality
$$y_I=y_O$$ to be verified, we are done.

[image]

Comment: thanks, interesting method, but I'm looking for something more synthetic

Answer (score 1):

According to the fact you mentioned, this solution proves that $2a=b+c$, where $a,b$ and $c$ are the sides of the triangle, and I assume you know how to show $\angle AIO =90 ^{\circ}$ by using this fact.

---

Based on the figure below, we have (try to check the details while everything is very simple):

$$\angle C A_1T=\frac{\angle C}{2}, \\ \angle TA_1D=\frac{\angle B}{2}, \\\angle O_1TX=\frac{\angle B-\angle C}{2}.$$

[image]

Now, let's assume $TD=DX=h$ and $r$ is the radius of the semicircle. We have (try to verify the details again):

$$A_1T=2CT\cos \frac{\angle C}{2}, \\ \frac{CT}{r}=\frac{\sin \frac{\angle C}{2}}{\cos \frac{\angle C}{2}}, \\ \frac{h}{A_1T}=\sin \frac{\angle B}{2}, \\ \cos (\frac{\angle B-\angle C}{2})=\frac{2h}{r}.$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{h}{r}= \frac{h}{A_1T} \times \frac{CT}{r} \times \frac{A_1T}{CT}=2\sin \frac{\angle B}{2}\sin \frac{\angle C}{2},$$

so,

$$\cos (\frac{\angle B-\angle C}{2})=4\sin \frac{\angle B}{2}\sin \frac{\angle C}{2},$$

which implies that:

$$\cos (\frac{\angle B+\angle C}{2})=\sin \frac{\angle A}{2}=2\sin \frac{\angle B}{2}\sin \frac{\angle C}{2}.$$

Now, note that:

$$\sin \angle B+\sin \angle C =2 \sin (\frac{\angle B+\angle C}{2}) \cos (\frac{\angle B-\angle C}{2})=8\cos \frac{\angle A}{2}\sin \frac{\angle B}{2}\sin \frac{\angle C}{2} \\= 4\cos \frac{\angle A}{2}\sin \frac{\angle A}{2}=2\sin \angle A \\ \implies b+c=2a.$$

We are done.

---

**PS: How to show that $2a=b+c$ implies $\angle AIO =90 ^{\circ}$?**

**Step 1:**

$$\sin \angle B+\sin \angle C=2\sin \angle A \implies \cos (\frac{\angle B-\angle C}{2})=4\sin \frac{\angle B}{2}\sin \frac{\angle C}{2}.$$

---

**Step 2:** According to the figure above,

$$\angle OAI=90^{\circ}-\angle C-\frac{\angle A}{2}.$$

---

**Step 3:** If $\angle AIO=x$, in $\triangle OIA$:

$$\frac{AI}{OA}=\frac{\sin (90^{\circ}+\angle C+\frac{\angle A}{2}-x)}{\sin x}. \ \ \ \ (*)$$

---

**Step 4:** In $\triangle AIB$, we have:

$$\frac{AI}{c}=\frac{\sin \frac{\angle B}{2}}{\sin \frac{\angle A+\angle B}{2}}\\ \implies AI=\frac{\sin \frac{\angle B}{2} \times 2AO \sin \angle C}{\sin \frac{\angle A+\angle B}{2}} \\ \implies \frac{AI}{OA}=4\sin \frac{\angle B}{2}\sin \frac{\angle C}{2}=\cos (\frac{\angle B-\angle C}{2}). \ \ \  \ (**)$$

---

**Step 5:** The equation arising from $(*)$ and $(**)$ yields $\angle AIO =90 ^{\circ}.$

---

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: As you see in figure a where $XY=O_1A=360$ we have $\angle AIO=108.95^o$ . For $90^o$ as shown in figure b,, $XY=360$ but $AO_1=400$, that is statement is right when $AO_1>XY$.

Comment: thanks, I didn't think it through